# Can't find controller directory

Tags: apache, zend-framework

I am trying to create a zend application at my apache web server and used httpdocs folder instead of public folder for my index.php. When I try to access the controller/action, it always looks at the httpdocs directory for the auth file. But since my controller is located in application/controller, it will throw an error. (I have already set the controller directory in the application.ini).

However when I changed the folder name from httpdocs to public and of course update my vhost.conf file, it works. So there must be some settings that must be set.

Now, I tried the same project and code in my lighttpd server and it is also working there.

Is there any setting/conf that must be set in apache server?

Any feedback will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Comment: I just needed to "rewrite" in my .htaccess file in httpdocs. I already have one in public directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/project-structure.rewrite.html).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

I just need rewriting in my .htaccess file under httpdocs directory.